# How to append/update the data in particular column using shell scripting

Tags: shell, awk, aix

I have a file in which it contain nearly 20 column. 
I need to update the 7th column , in which i need to add 8 zero's to it

eg : tmp.txt

```
756 S#017925 5608 R88 X3GU0C LIC 200 00000000000 
756 S#017925 5608 R88 M3GURA LIC 200 00000000000
```

The 7th column(bolder one) i need to append 8 zeros to it i.e "00000000200" .

expected output :

```
  756 S#017925 5608 R88 X3GU0C LIC 00000000200 00000000000
```

I tried using awk command

```
awk -F' ' '{print "00000000"$7}' tmp.txt > tmp1.txt
```

but it is returning like :

```
00000000200
00000000200
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly do this:

```
$ awk '{$7="0000000"$7}1' file
756 S#017925 5608 R88 X3GU0C LIC 0000000200 00000000000
756 S#017925 5608 R88 M3GURA LIC 0000000200 00000000000
```

It sets the 7th field the same way you were doing it. Then, prints the full line with `1`.

---

If your number `8` happens to be variable on time, it can be handy to use `printf` together with `%0XXi` to make the variable contain `XX` digits (there will be `XX  - length_number`) number of leading `0`s). To store the value in a variable, we use `sprintf`. [Thanks to triplee for the idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25403286/how-to-append-update-the-data-in-particular-column-using-shell-scripting#comment39622917_25403337)!

```
$ awk '{ $7 = sprintf("%011i", $7) } 1' file
756 S#017925 5608 R88 X3GU0C LIC 00000000200 00000000000
756 S#017925 5608 R88 M3GURA LIC 00000000200 00000000000
```

---

What was wrong in your attempt?

```
awk -F' ' '{print "00000000"$7}' tmp.txt > tmp1.txt
```

- `print "00000000"$7` you are just printing the 7th field. Using `1` you make awk perform its default action: `{print $0}`, which means that it prints the full line.
- also, there is no need to use `-F' '`, as it is the default.

Comment: Maybe use `{ $7 = sprintf("%010i", $7) } 1` if you require padding to a particular length rather than just adding a static number of zeros.

Comment: Nice, @tripleee It was in fact `%011i` because the number is 3 digits long. I added it to my answer, thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot fedorqui .. Works as expected.